# Model variables remain undefined if not edited in the partial: Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a `ng-model="name"` in the partial and in the controller inside a function I create an object like:

```
var data= {};
data['name'] = $scope.name;
```

But on the execution of the code the data remains an empty object as the $scope.name remains undefined.

1. How to resolve this ?
2. I have many vars in the partial and I will like to use them directly without having to declare them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will not automatically set your scope properties to an empty string just by using them in your view, they will remain undefined until you set them or change the value.

Comment: No way possible that it can set to empty string globally ?

Comment: no, you could use `ng-init="name=''"` in each instance or just set the values in your controller of course, or create a directive that you would add to each input that would initialize the model to a blank string if it is undefined, but no way to do it without some code.